# Remove direct parent node of selection (<b>)

Tags: javascript, html, text

I would like to remove and add the `<b>` tag to a selected text just by clicking on it.

I can already enclose selected text in the `<b>` tag via:

```
if (window.getSelection) 
{
    selection = getSelection();

    var newNode = document.createElement("b");
    range.surroundContents(newNode);        
}
```

Now that time I would like to have a method to remove the `<b>` tag I added beforehand, but the commonly shown method of using `range.commonAncestorContainer` would give me lowest parent of the `<div>` type.

As a part of debugging I simply modified the code I used to add the `<b>` tag (to make sure I had a tag, I also first added it) to remove the parent node.

```
if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = getSelection();

    var newNode = document.createElement("b");
    range.surroundContents(newNode);
    node = range.commonAncestorContainer;
    node.remove();
}
```

This will remove the parent `<div>` of the newly added `<b>` tag, instead of only the `<b>` tag itself.

For reference, here is the HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="input" class="inputblock" onclick="getClick()" onkeypress="changeNodeType(event)" data-text="Please paste your text here."></div>
```

The `<b>` tag will be created within text pasted into the shown `<div>`.

The fact that it also removes the content can be ignored. I'll find a way to work with that.

Comment: I don't see any HTML so I have no idea if this `<div>` is actually where you say it is or where this `<b>` and text is in relation to `<div>` as parent of `<b>` and the text of `<div>` is a textNode sibling of `<b>`? If `<b>` falls in the forest and no one's around does `<div>` make any noise?

Comment: I edited that in. What is th diverence between a '<b>'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I unfortunately don't have as much time as I'd like to spend to write out a full code solution, but this is how I've solved this in the past:

1. Normalize your range. This is the hardest part. IE, edge, and different browsers behave differently so you will need to handle a lot of special edge cases. For example if the range is right before an empty text node, IE will do wonky things
2. For your the start and endcontainer, if they are text nodes, do nothing
3. Otherwise, you need to use a `NodeIterator` to do an in-order traversal and walk to the next node for the start container, and the previous node for the end container. This solves the case where, when you select something like `<b>hello</b>`, the selection can either be `|<b>hello</b>|` or `<b>|hello|</b>`. By normalizing and walking down the tree, you will end up with a - mostly equivalent - selection of `<b>|hello|</b>` in both cases. It's hard to explain this without pictures, so I would encourage you to draw out the DOM tree and do a walk to the next innermost child of the start container and the previous innermost child of the end container.

   4. Once you have nestled your way down, you can start to walk UP the tree to find a bold tag. This is simply `node.contains('b')`;
   5. Do that for both the start and end node, then see if you're pointing to the same bold tag, and that the text content is the same as your selection.
   6. If so, you have found your bold tag to nuke.

It's a non-trivial amount of code, and it requires a bunch of testing due really wonky edge cases with setting the selection and range in browsers. I have fought contenteditable for a long time :-) and I wish you the best of luck